# How do you properly close a JDBC connection for reuse?

Tags: java, android, database, jdbc

I am able to retrieve information from my database the first time I establish a connection but whenever I try to reconnect to the database and retrieve more information from the database in different classes it doesn't work. I am trying to put the information I am retrieving from the database into TextViews in Android Studio but they keep showing up as "null". I will show you the code from when I first connect to the database, my connection manager class, and the next time I try to connect to the database. I think it might be because the connection isn't properly being closed but I make sure to close the resultSet, statement, and connection.

This is for my senior project which is due soon so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Here is the code from the first time I connect to the database:

```
public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    public final String mEmail;
    private final String mPassword;

    UserLoginTask(String email, String password) {
        mEmail = email;
        mPassword = password;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Connection conn = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
            Statement st = null;
            if (conn != null)
                st = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = null;
            if (st != null)
                resultSet = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE email='" + mEmail + "'");
            int counter = 0;
            if (resultSet != null)
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    counter++;
                    try {
                        if (mPassword.equals(resultSet.getString("password"))) {
                            UserLoginInfo.userEmail = mEmail;
                            UserLoginInfo.fName = resultSet.getString("firstname");
                            UserLoginInfo.lName = resultSet.getString("lastname");
                            st.close();
                            resultSet.close();
                            conn.close();
                            return (true);
                        } else
                            return (false);
                    } catch (SQLException e3) {
                        e3.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            if (counter == 0)
                return false;
            // TODO: register the new account here.
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute ( final Boolean success){
        mAuthTask = null;
        showProgress(false);
        if (success) {
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent("NavDrawer"));
        } else {
            mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
            mPasswordView.requestFocus();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled () {
        mAuthTask = null;
        showProgress(false);
    }
}
```

Here is my connection manager class:

```
package com.capstone.hammond.wallstreetfantasyleaguefinal;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ConnectionManager {


private static String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@141.216.24.31:1521:fsdb";
private static String driverName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
private static String username = "xxxx";
private static String password = "xxxx";
private static Connection con;


public static Connection getConnection() {
    try {
        Class.forName(driverName);
        try {
            if(con !=null)
                return con;
            else
                return con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            // log an exception. for example:
            System.out.println("Failed to create the database connection.");
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        // log an exception. for example:
        System.out.println("Driver not found.");
    }
    return con;
}

}
```

Here is the second time I try to connect to the database:

```
package com.capstone.hammond.wallstreetfantasyleaguefinal;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class WeeklyMatchFragment extends Fragment {
    TextView user1;
    TextView user2;
    TextView bank1;
    TextView bank2;
    String oppFName;
    String oppLName;
    float oppBank;

View rootview;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_weekly_match, container, false);
    return rootview;

}

public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    new MatchDetails();

    user1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.user1);
    user1.setText(UserLoginInfo.fName + " " + UserLoginInfo.lName);
    bank1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.bank1);
    bank1.setText("Bank: " + UserLoginInfo.bank);
    user2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.user2);
    user2.setText(oppFName + " " + oppLName);
    bank2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.bank2);
    bank2.setText("Bank: " + oppBank);


}

public class MatchDetails extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Connection conn = ConnectionManager.getConnection();

            ResultSet rs = null;
            Statement st = null;
            if (conn != null)
                st = conn.createStatement();
            if (st != null)
                rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM L1_Standings WHERE EMAIL = '" + UserLoginInfo.userEmail + "'");
            if (rs != null)
                while (rs.next()) {
                    try {
                        UserLoginInfo.bank = rs.getInt("BANK");
                        UserLoginInfo.currOpp = rs.getInt("CURR_OPP");
                    } catch (SQLException e3) {
                        e3.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            Statement st1 = null;

            if (conn != null)
                st1 = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs1 = null;
            if (st != null)
                rs1 = st1.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM USERINFO WHERE EMAIL = '" + UserLoginInfo.currOpp + "'");
            if (rs1 != null)
                while (rs1.next()) {
                    try {
                        oppFName = rs1.getString("FIRSTNAME");
                        oppLName = rs1.getString("LASTNAME");
                    } catch (SQLException e3) {
                        e3.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Just close it, with close(), *in the `finally` block.*

Answer (score 0):

You should close the JDBC connection in finally block.

If you are using JAVA 7, use try with resource statement - [try-with-Resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html);

Comment: Yeah but in the try section I am returning true so would it even reach the finally statement?

Comment: Is there any way to just keep the connection open and use it in other classes without opening up a new connection each time I want to retrieve data from my database?

Comment: You should add the finally in MatchDetails. doInBackground  method since you are using connection there. Add finally block at end and then close the connection.

Comment: Ok, do I need to close the resultSets, statements, and the connection? Or just say close(); like EJP said?

Comment: yes close resultSets, statements, and the connection

Comment: Ok. Is there any way to execute multiple queries without opening a new connection every time?

Comment: With the same connection, you can create multiple statements and execute queries. You need not open new connection every time.

Comment: Even from different classes? By the way, thanks for taking the time to answer my questions.

Comment: Yes you can do that, But make sure that you open connection in one class and execute some query.  move to next class but still use the same connection and close connection at end.

I would also suggest to explore possibility of making ConnectionManager Singleton / use connection pooling if you have time.

Answer (score 0):

About your questions:

- You should alternatively a) close explicitly the connection b) write and call a close() method in ConnectionManager that does it
- it's a bad idea to reuse the same connection across several tasks. Although this could sound good, in a multithreaded environment it is not efficient. Direct connection must be "closed" as soon as possible. What you're looking for is a ConnectionPool
- yes you must close every database resource (in inverse order): ResultSet, Statement, Connection

Statements, Resultsets and connections are object wrappers of outbound network and database resources, and therefore they aren't infinite (both on client and server side). Leaving those resources open has therefore a different aspect, both on client and on server side.

On client side you're marking as busy some (outbound) resource (i.e. connection) that is instead idle (I mean, between one usage and another). If you don't release that resource that will be still marked as busy on server side as well (here I mean the server side representation of that resource), and since the server usually has a limited number of "slots" available, another client could see denied a request for a new connection, and this is wrong because maybe you're not actually using that.

Comment: Ok, that's a good idea. I will try to create a method in Connection Manager to close the connection. I just don't understand why it wouldn't work the second time I try to access the database when I explicitly close the connection, resultSet, and statements.

Comment: You said right: it "would" (or "should") work.I edited my answer because a comment cannot  be so long ;)

Answer (score 0):

I got it to finally work somewhat. The biggest issue was not that I wasn't closing the connection the first time, but I was not properly calling my Asynctask. It needed to be:

```
new MatchDetails().execute((Void) null);
```

Now the only problem that I am having is that the textViews do not change until the fragment opens twice. The first time I open them they appear null, but when I open it again they change to what they are supposed to be. Does anyone have any ideas for that?

Comment: I think you should accept an answer and open another (swing related) question